# multiple taxonomies on a custom post type

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I created a CPT for my WP-Blog and now I have some issues with the permalinks.
First I started with a CPT called events. Then I wanted to categorize these events and made a custom taxonomy.

```
register_taxonomy('khbl_eventcategory','khbl_events', array(
'label' => __('Event Category'),
'labels' => $labels,
'hierarchical' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'rewrite' => false,
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'event-category' ),
));
```

So far so good. Then I wanted to add an artist field for listing all participating artists of the event.

```
register_taxonomy(  'artist', 'khbl_events',  
    array(
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'label' => 'Event Artists', 
        'query_var' => true, 
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'artist'))
        );
}
```

Since I added the second taxonomy the permalinks for the single-pages of the events don't work anymore even if I remove the artist-taxonomy. I can disable the rewriting for the CPT but I want to understand what the problem is. Is it even possible to have two taxonomies on a single post type?

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution after some trial and error.

Just use the following function at the end of the Custom Post Type init:

```
flush_rewrite_rules( false );
```

Comment: That should not be a solution actually.